# Prove what an infinite union or intersection of a set will be

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I am trying to prove qualities about the infinite union and intersection of sets. For example. All of them relate to intervals over the real numbers.

$$ \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty[i, i+1] $$
$$ \bigcap_{i=1}^\infty[\frac{-1}{i}, \frac 1i] $$

For the first one I believe it is the positive real numbers. Which seems clear but I don't know how to show this mathematically. The thought of using some kind of epsilon proof keeps coming to mind but not sure how to do that either.

As for the second one I am less sure of what it will be but because each interval gets smaller and it is the intersection I am going to say the empty set? How would I prove this? Show that no elements are in it? Again, not sure how to do that.

Comment: For the first: What about $1/2$? For the second: Can you find a number (or more numbers) which are contained in each interval $[-1/i,1/i]$?

Comment: If you want to prove that the second set is the empty set, you would have to prove for an arbitrary real $r$ that there is at least one $i \geq 1$ such that $r \notin [-1/i,1/i]$.

Comment: @sranthrop Thank you that was because I incorrectly wrote the problem here it should be from i=0. I won't change it because it should still help me understand

Comment: Do you know Archimedean property of real numbers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For the first one I believe it is the positive real numbers.

You're almost correct. It's a bit less than that, since $\frac12$ does not belong to the set.

However, all numbers *greater or equal to $1$* do belong to the set. In other words, the set is equal to $[1,\infty)$

To actually prove two sets $X, Y$ are equal, you have to

1. prove that every $x\in X$ is also an element of $Y$ and
2. prove that every $y\in Y$ is also an element of $X$.

In your case, for the first set, you have to:

1. For every $x\in \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty[i, i+1]$, prove that $x\in[1,\infty)$ (*this is the easy part*)
2. For every $x$ in $[1, \infty)$, prove that $x\in\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty[i, i+1]$.

The second step is where most of the work lies, but it shouldn't be too difficult. As so many other math proofs, you start by taking any $x\in [1,\infty)$.

Remember that $x\in \bigcup A_i$ if and only if there exists some $i$ such that $x\in A_i$. This means that to prove that $x\in[0,\infty)$ is also in $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty[i, i+1]$, you have to prove that there exists *some* $i$ such that $x\in[i,i+1]$.

Take a look at the **largest** integer that is smaller than $x$, and you should be done.

---

> As for the second one I am less sure of what it will be but because each interval gets smaller and it is the intersection I am going to say the empty set?

Again, almost correct.

The intersection $$\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty A_i$$

is defined as

$$\{x| \forall i: x\in A_i\}$$

So it is the set of those numbers that are in **all** sets $[-\frac1i, \frac1i]$. Can you think of a number that's in all of those sets?

Comment: Thank you that helps a lot. As for the second part if would just be zero right?

Comment: @JohnO'Neil Correct! Now you still have to prove that, of course. So you have to prove that (1) zero is in the set and that (2) no other number is in the set.

Comment: I am still having a little bit of trouble doing that any hints? It seems intuitive but I have no idea how to express it properly

Comment: @JohnO'Neil Just do it one step at a time. Can you prove that $0$ is in the intersection?

Comment: @JohnO'Neil remember, $x$ is in the intersection if it is in $[-\frac1i, \frac1i]$ for **all** values of $i$.

Comment: Is it just as simple as saying -1/i < 0 < 1/i for all i?

Comment: @JohnO'Neil it's just that simple, yes :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58380/discussion-between-john-oneil-and-5xum).